# How to make sure several SELECTs are isolated?

Tags: mysql, select, transactions

When we have to use several different SELECT queries to get data from various locations in the database, how to make sure they are isolated from queries such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE so that we can be sure that data selected are consistent with each other and not changed in between?

I know I can use transaction to achieve the same effect for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE so changes are applied as a whole or not. But does it isolate SELECTs as well?

For example, 3 SELECT queries return 3 different values, either:

1, 3, 5

Or:

2, 4, 8

3 update queries are constantly switching the values. How to make sure I get either:

1, 3, 5

Or:

2, 4, 8

But not anything in between such as: 2, 3, 5, nor 2, 4, 5, etc.

I know I can get those updates in a transaction but I want double check.

So would it work if I put those 3 SELECTs in a transaction?

Comment: Relational databases are generally ACID compliant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).  The "I" is isolation, which is what you are asking for.  You need to check the MySQL documentation to see if the storage engine you are using fully supports isolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking how to read the database "consistently".  Such matters are determined by the [transaction isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level).  You want [`REPEATABLE READ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read):

> This is the default isolation level for `InnoDB`. For [consistent reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_consistent_read), there is an important difference from the [`READ COMMITTED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed) isolation level: All consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first read. This convention means that if you issue several plain (nonlocking) [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statements within the same transaction, these [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statements are consistent also with respect to each other. See [Section 14.2.7.2, “Consistent Nonlocking Reads”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-consistent-read.html).

So, yes, it will work if you put your `SELECT` statements within a single transaction—provided that the transaction's isolation level is `REPEATABLE READ` (the default).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Normally exactly this is prevented with transactions. Look up transaction isolation levels of your dbms. For mysql for example see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/dynindex-isolevel.html
Of Course the update statements that change all three values must be in ONE transaction. If they are in three different transactions then your select could catch states in beetween the updates.